# Adding Intel MKL and MKL-DNN in Docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, pytorch, intel-mkl

I have ML code (e.g. Numpy, Scipy, LightGBM, PyTorch) deployed with Docker. I am using Python with Poetry, installing packages with pip.

What should I do in order to use MKL and MKL-DNN? I know that the most standard way is to use Anaconda, but I cannot (large business, without commercial Anaconda license).

Will `pip install mkl` suffice?

How to install MKL-DNN, so that PyTorch will use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will pip install mkl suffice?

No, it will not, see the section in the [numpy install docs](https://numpy.org/install/):

> The NumPy wheels on PyPI, which is what pip installs, are built with OpenBLAS. The OpenBLAS libraries are included in the wheel. This makes the wheel larger, and if a user installs (for example) SciPy as well, they will now have two copies of OpenBLAS on disk.

So you will need to built numpy from source.

> I know that the most standard way is to use Anaconda, but I cannot (large business, without commercial Anaconda license).

Have you considered using miniforge and miniconda? IANAL, but I am quite certain that you are just not allowed to use the ana-/miniconda distributions and the anaconda channel in large scale commercial products, but [conda-forge can still be used free of charge](https://conda-forge.org/blog/posts/2020-11-20-anaconda-tos/). You should be able to set up all the requirements that you mentioned from conda-forge. At least you would probably have an easier time compiling pytorch from source

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add MKL to my docker container (debian based) reading intel documentation: I failed.

However, there is a docker image [OneAPI docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/intel/oneapi) that comes with numpy (1.21 which is eight month old) and mkl as default BLAS.
Here is what numpy returns on my machine (a laptop with a i7-i10875H )

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__config__.show()
blas_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/include']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/include']
lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/include']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['mkl_rt', 'pthread']
    library_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/lib']
    define_macros = [('SCIPY_MKL_H', None), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/opt/intel/oneapi/intelpython/latest/include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42
    found = 
    not found = AVX512_ICL
```

However, I tried with anaconda and an basic docker image, and to my surprise, the anaconda virtual env used the CBLAS and my docker image used the Openblas BLAS.

I did not perform benchmarks, but since the mkl implementation uses all instruction set architecture except AVX512_ICL, I would expect it to be faster.

###### Anaconda

I was also surprise to test that in my anaconda environment, and to my surprise, **the blas is not mkl**.

```
$ conda create -n test numpy --yes
[...]
$ conda activate test

>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__config__.show()
blas_info:
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/adrienpacifico/anaconda3/envs/test/lib']
    include_dirs = ['/home/adrienpacifico/anaconda3/envs/test/include']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
blas_opt_info:
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    libraries = ['cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/adrienpacifico/anaconda3/envs/test/lib']
    include_dirs = ['/home/adrienpacifico/anaconda3/envs/test/include']
    language = c
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/adrienpacifico/anaconda3/envs/test/lib']
    language = f77
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['lapack', 'blas', 'lapack', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas', 'cblas', 'blas']
    library_dirs = ['/home/adrienpacifico/anaconda3/envs/test/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('NO_ATLAS_INFO', 1), ('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    include_dirs = ['/home/adrienpacifico/anaconda3/envs/test/include']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```

My `base` environment uses openblas.

##### My docker image based on python image --> Openblas

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10
ENV SHELL=/bin/bash
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y sudo libaio1 wget unzip htop
RUN pip install numpy
```

```
openblas64__info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
blas_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
openblas64__lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
lapack_ilp64_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas64_', 'openblas64_']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_'), ('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('HAVE_LAPACKE', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/usr/local/lib']
Supported SIMD extensions in this NumPy install:
    baseline = SSE,SSE2,SSE3
    found = SSSE3,SSE41,POPCNT,SSE42,AVX,F16C,FMA3,AVX2
    not found = AVX512F,AVX512CD,AVX512_KNL,AVX512_KNM,AVX512_SKX,AVX512_CLX,AVX512_CNL,AVX512_ICL
```